# Continuity Requirements for PDE Strong Solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Consider a stationary heat transfer problem as an example, the governing equation is the following second order pde:
$$-k\Delta T(x)=\dot{q}(x) $$

In the all text books it said that the strong solution of the equation $T(x)$ which satisfy the above equation needs to be continuous in $\Omega$ and also its first derivative $\frac{d}{dx} T(x)$ should be continuous in $\Omega$ to make sure that the second derivative would exist at every point in $\Omega$

My questions is: is that a sufficient conditions? does continuity in first derivative insure existence of the second derivative?

I think that we could have a situation where we have a continuous first derivative but the second derivative doesn't exist, for example if $$\frac{d}{dx} T(x)=\lvert x\rvert$$ Then the second derivative at $x=0$ doesn't exist

Is  there something that I am missing?

Thanks in advance